# How to set up S3 bucket with nginx?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I've encountered with the problem. I created S3 bucket with default permissions and uploaded files for my website (js, css, html) but when i try to access it via browser i get access denied. So i set up EC2 instance and run nginx on it, as i figured in order to proxy my S3 bucket via nginx to access the website i  need to put in the nginx config the aws access key id and secret access key  to obtain them i created the IAM user with full access to my S3 bucket. But i can't correctly configure nginx proxy with these access keys to the S3 bucket. What i need to achieve is that user hits my website then it goes to my EC2 instance and nginx proxy to the S3 bucket and the S3 bucket can only be accessed via nginx as i provide credentials for it. The question is, am i doing it wrong? Maybe i shouldn't make the S3 bucket private and then i can easily proxy it with nginx but then everybody can access the S3 bucket whether its via nginx or by the default S3 domain in the browser. Can you help? How should i do it the right way?

Comment: You need to set your S3 bucket up for [public website hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) for either direct or proxied access. Nginx is just making a http request, not using your keys.

Comment: @Tim, there are components like https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_aws_auth so it's not out of the question for Nginx to be authing these requests.

Comment: @jerichofs start by enabling logging on the bucket, then matching up the log entries to your testing.  `<RequestId>` in the XML error and `x-amz-request-id` in the response headers matches against the `Request ID` field in the S3 logs.  Do you see your tests?  Are the object keys correct and the logged credentials correct?